# Text-align not working

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website but for some reason my text align is not working. When i type it, it has no affect on it. I need some help. I want the content in my dropdown menu to be aligned to the left.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta  charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>My Cycle - Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="heading">
                <img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/5d32881.png" id="image_symbol"></img>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar">
                <ul id="main_navbar">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" style="z-index: -1" class="active">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropbtn" style="z-index: -1">Rent</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <a href="rental/mountain_bikes.html">Mountain Bikes</a>
                            <a href="rental/hybrid_bikes.html">Hybrid Bikes</a>
                            <a href="rental/road_bikes.html">Road Bikes</a>
                            <a href="rental/city_bikes.html">City Bikes</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="faq.html" style="z-index: -1">FAQ's</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html" style="z-index: -1">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="sub_navbar">
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact_us.html" style="margin-right: 10px">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="log_in.php">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="sign_up.html">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section>

        </section>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif, Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main_navbar {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#main_navbar li, #sub_navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 5em;
}

#main_navbar li a, #sub_navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#sub_navbar {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:active {
  color: #32673f;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  min-width: 150px;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(90%,0);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

#image_symbol {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

header {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#sub_navbar li a:hover, #main_navbar li a:hover {
  color: #FFCC00;
}

#sub_navbar li .active, #main_navbar li .active {
  color: #09c;
}

header {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see a `text-align: left;` anywhere?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's generally appreciated if you want someone to help you, to make a minimal example of your issue and add a Codepen or JsFiddle or equivalent so we don't have to copy paste your stuff to reproduce the issue. In your case though, all I see is `text-align: center` explicitly set all over where you probably wouldn't want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove

```
text-align: center;
```

from here

```
#main_navbar li a, #sub_navbar li a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1em;
text-align: center;
color: black;
font-weight: normal;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As @Violetluna said, remove `text-align: center;` from `#main_navbar li a, #sub_navbar li a`

```
#main_navbar li a, #sub_navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

You don't have to put `text-align: left;` on it because it is the default property.

Also, the syntax of the `<img>` is incorrect, it is not :

```
<img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/5d32881.png" id="image_symbol"></img>
```

It is :

```
<img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/5d32881.png" id="image_symbol" />
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g2acmts2/)